# Position of "wohl" in a sentence

Tags: word-usage, sentence-structure, adjective

> Die Schüler werden wohl eine Klassenfahrt machen.

‎Warum steht *wohl* vor *eine Klassenfahrt* in diesem Satz?

Comment: _wohl_ steht doch **vor** _eine Klassenfahrt_. Hast Du ein _nicht_ in Deiner Frage vergessen?

Comment: Ich möchte wissen, warum (wohl) vor (eine Klassenfahrt) steht?

Comment: *Wohl* has more than one meaning, here it would translate to *presumably*. What problem do you have with that position?

Comment: Rückfrage: warum soll es falsch sein? Welches Verständnis besteht bei der vorliegenden Konstruktion und wie würde die (gedachte) Intention nach eigenem Wissen geschrieben werden?

Comment: Ich denke, es wird einfach nach einer Regel gefragt. Adverb vor Akkusativobjekt o.ä.

Comment: @guidot yes, I don't know where I should use it in a sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, *wohl* is a modal adverb, indicating an assumption.

> The students will *probably* make a school trip.

Comment: Is not (wohl) in an adverb position?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The sentence is in the future tense, therefore (werden) is added to (machen) as a modal verb. Just like (will) in English. The modal adverb’s (wohl) correct position is directly following the verb, or—if present—the modal verb.

Comment: You cannot put it as simply as that. In *die Studenten werden sie wohl machen*, the adverb does not directly follow the verb and is preceded by the object.

Comment: True. (Wohl) can be in multiple positions. However, that would have a slightly different meaning. The original sentence indicates that the students will probably make the trip (having other options). Your example indicates that they were undecided whether to make the trip (as opposed to not doing it, having no other options) and now appear to have come to a conclusion. So the original sentence is focused on *what* they do. Yours more on *whether* they do it.